# Django 1.7 mongo can't run tests

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I'm using two database. My basic is postgres database and secound is mongodb. My project run fine but when i run tests:
My config - when I comment default_mongo then tests runs fine:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'TEST_NAME': 'my_test_sql',
        'TEST_USER': 'test_sql_user',
        'TEST_PASSWORD': 'password'
    },
    'default_mongo': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
        'NAME': 'bid',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '27017',
        'SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS': False,
        'TEST_NAME': 'my_test_mongodb',
        'TEST_USER': 'test_mongo_user',
        'TEST_PASSWORD': 'password'
    },
}
```

**./manage.py test**

```
$ ./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Destroying old test database 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/t/py/django/bid/src/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/t/py/django/bid/src/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/t/py/django/bid/src/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 50, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/t/py/django/bid/src/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/t/py/django/bid/src/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 71, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/t/py/django/bid/src/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/t/py/django/bid/src/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 88, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/home/t/py/django/bid/src/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 147, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/home/t/py/django/bid/src/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 109, in setup_databases
    return setup_databases(self.verbosity, self.interactive, **kwargs)
  File "/home/t/py/django/bid/src/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 299, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
TypeError: create_test_db() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialize'
```

Comment: Any updates? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: still open, now I don't use 2nd database but maybe in future